# How to remove interaction on invisible part of circular imageview?

Tags: android, imageview, touch-event

I have an ImageView with circular shaped drwables.
I have some interaction on the image using onTouch.

How can I remove onTouch from imageview on those parts that are outside circular shape?

Image view is Square shaped and I have circular image inside it.
I want to remove touch outside my visible circular part!!

Comment: do you know a mathematical formula for any points that are inside some circle of center x, y and radius r?

Comment: Is there a way to generate circular image view... I mean the whole container is circular in shape

Comment: of course not, any View is rectangular